# R help needed for my cumulative percentage function

Tags: r, function, cumulative-frequency

A recent change (be it in R or somewhere else) has made my previously working function stop working. The function is designed to generate two columns that tell me what the percentile score (see `df2$CumPercent` is for a given score on a survey (see `df2$V1`).  I have therefore made a few changes to the manual version of the logic, which is working well. When I apply the same logic within a function it spits out an error stating that the `Var1` variable is not found. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

```
df5 <- structure(list(MyVariable = c(4.66666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
                                     5.66666666666667, 4.5, 5.16666666666667, 4.5, 1, 3.83333333333333, 
                                     2, 4, 2.33333333333333, 5.5, 5.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
                                     5.66666666666667, 2.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
                                     5.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 4.5, 3.66666666666667, 
                                     3.83333333333333, 2, 5, 2.83333333333333, 3, 4.83333333333333, 
                                     5.16666666666667, 3, 5.16666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 
                                     2.16666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3.5, 4.5, 3, 5.16666666666667, 
                                     4.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
                                     2.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
                                     5.16666666666667, 6.16666666666667, 1.83333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
                                     4.5, 4.83333333333333, 5.5, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
                                     4.83333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 4.5, 4.16666666666667, 5.5, 
                                     4.5, 4.83333333333333, 5, 1, 4.5, 5, 2.33333333333333, 4, 3.5, 
                                     3.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 1.5, 5.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
                                     5.16666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 6, 4.33333333333333, 
                                     2.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 5.83333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
                                     5, 5.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 
                                     4.83333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 5, 3.5, 5, 5.5, 4.66666666666667, 
                                     5.33333333333333, 5.5, 3.66666666666667, 1.83333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
                                     5, 5.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 
                                     3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 2.5, 5.33333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 
                                     4.16666666666667, 3.5, 3, 5.16666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
                                     5.83333333333333, 4, 5.33333333333333, 6, 3.16666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
                                     4.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 3.5, 4.66666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
                                     4, 4.33333333333333, 3.5, 3.16666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 
                                     4.66666666666667, 2.83333333333333, 4, 2.5, 2.83333333333333, 
                                     4.83333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 4.5, 3.83333333333333, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                   -145L), class = "data.frame")

#Manual version of the cumulative percent logic (which works as intended)
PercentilesRaw <- data.frame(seq(from=0, to=7, by=.01)) #Create every increment of percentile as vector
colnames(PercentilesRaw)[colnames(PercentilesRaw)=="seq.from...0..to...7..by...0.01."] <- "V1" #Rename percentile column name
df <- data.frame(table(df5$MyVariable)) #Count the number of original values in the column
df[,"Var1"] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,"Var1"])) #The table function above produces factor levels so need to convert to numeric
V1 <- df[,"Var1"] #Make a vector from the Var1 column
Frequency <- df[,"Freq"] #Make a vector from the Freq column
CumSum <- cumsum(df[,"Freq"]) #Calculate a cumulative sum from the Freq column
CumPercent <- CumSum/sum(df[,"Freq"])*100 #Calculate the cumulative percentage vector
CumPercent <- round(CumPercent,2) #Round the cumulative percentage vector to 2 dp
output <- cbind(round(V1,2), CumPercent) #Map the cumulative percent results to the V1 vector
df2 <- data.frame(output) #Convert the two columns into a df

#Now attempt to convert into a function.
cpave1 <- function(x) {
  PercentilesRaw <- data.frame(seq(from=0, to=7, by=.01)) #Create every increment of percentile as vector
  colnames(PercentilesRaw)[colnames(PercentilesRaw)=="seq.from...0..to...7..by...0.01."] <- "V1" #Rename percentile column name
  df <- data.frame(table(x)) #Count the number of original values in the column
  df[,"Var1"] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,"Var1"])) #The table function above produces factor levels so need to convert to numeric
  V1 <- df[,"Var1"] #Make a vector from the Var1 column
  Frequency <- df[,"Freq"] #Make a vector from the Freq column
  CumSum <- cumsum(df[,"Freq"]) #Calculate a cumulative sum from the Freq column
  CumPercent <- CumSum/sum(df[,"Freq"])*100 #Calculate the cumulative percentage vector
  CumPercent <- round(CumPercent,2) #Round the cumulative percentage vector to 2 dp
  output <- cbind(round(V1,2), CumPercent) #Map the cumulative percent results to the V1 vector
  df2 <- data.frame(output) #Convert the two columns into a df
}

#Apply function to the MyVariable column.
MyVariable <- cpave1(df5$MyVariable)
```

Comment: I think it's seeing no `df$Var1` on the right side of this line of the function: `df[,"Var1"] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,"Var1"]))`

Comment: when are you using `PercentilesRaw `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests there is no `"Var1"` column in your data. The column is called `x`. Here is a shorter and updated version of your function which returns the same output.

```
cpave1 <- function(x) {
  df <- type.convert(data.frame(table(x)), as.is = TRUE)
  data.frame(V1 = round(df$x ,2), 
             CumPercent = round(cumsum(df$Freq)/sum(df$Freq)*100, 2))
}
cpave1(df5$MyVariable)

#     V1 CumPercent
#1  1.00       1.38
#2  1.33       2.76
#3  1.50       3.45
#4  1.83       4.83
#5  2.00       6.21
#6  2.17       8.28
#7  2.33      12.41
#8  2.50      13.79
#...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly well, but I don't understand why. I also don't understand how you could tell that the function was producing an`x`? The manual version produces `Var1` so why didn't my function do the same (the error message is not helpful for me)?

Comment: I had to debug the function to find that out. The column name is given based on the name of the input. For example `x <- df5$MyVariable;data.frame(table(x))` produces column with `x`.

Comment: Ahh I see, that is really good to know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think that `data.table` is best way:
Solution without making a function is simple:

```
library(data.table)
df5 <- data.table(df5)
df5[, .N, MyVariable][order(MyVariable)][, .(MyVariable, CumPercent = round(cumsum(N) / sum(N), 4) * 100)]
```

or if you want to make a function:

```
library(data.table)
df5 <- data.table(df5)
cpave2 <- function(data, colname) {
  data[, .N, get(colname)][order(get)][, .(Values = get,
                                           CumPercent = round(cumsum(N) / sum(N), 4) * 100)]
  
}

cpave2(df5, 'MyVariable')
```